# issue with preg_replace not returning anything

Tags: regex

I am doing some checks on the name of a file but even though my regular expression works when I test it on regex101.com once I put it in the real environment it always returns nothing...

I have a file name "abc123.jpg" stored in $_FILES["picture"]["name"]

If I do:

```
str_replace('a','',$_FILES["picture"]["name"])
```

I get 'bc123.jpg'
If I do:

```
preg_replace('a','',$_FILES["picture"]["name"])
```

I get '' (nothing).

How is this possible?
What am I missing?

Ultimately my regex would be:

```
/[^\w\.\-]/g
```

to remove all non-alphanumerical characters except for underscore, dash and the dot (needed before the file type extension)

Comment: `preg_replace('~a~','',$_FILES["picture"]["name"])` - you forgot delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use [regex delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). I suggest you use

```
$s = preg_replace('~[^\w.-]+~', '', $s);
                   ^        ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mwecRH/1/). Here, I am using `~` as a regex delimiter.

Note that the `-` at the end of the character class is treated as a hyphen and does not have to be escaped. `.` inside a  character class is always treated as a literal dot, no need escaping it either. Since you want to remove those symbols, it is a good idea to remove them in consecutive chunks, hence, I suggest adding a `+` quantifier after the character class, to match 1 or more occurrences.

Note that `/g` modifier is not supported by PHP regex, `preg_replace` replaces all non-overlapping occurrences by default.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I had forgotten the delimiter in the example but I did have delimiters in my actual regex that I was testing, however I did not know that the /g modifier isn't supported by PHP and I think that is why it wasn't working. Thanks for clarifying that and providing a working example!